# Javassist ClassPool instantiation fails silently

Tags: java, javassist, javaagents

I'm currently trying to write a Java agent for monitoring purposes. I use maven as build system.

I have a Agent.java file:

```java
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class Agent {

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        System.out.println("Running premain");

        MonitorTransformer transformer = new MonitorTransformer();
        inst.addTransformer( transformer );
    }

}
```

And a MonitorTransformer.java file implementing the ClassFileTransformer interface by simply overriding the `transform` method.
This is how the implementation looks like:

```java
@Override
    public byte[] transform(
        ClassLoader loader,
        String className,
        Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
        ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
        byte[] classfileBuffer
    ) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        System.out.println("Before ClassPool Instantiation");
        ClassPool classPool = new ClassPool();
        System.out.println("After ClassPool Instantiation");

        return classfileBuffer;
    }
```

When i run the agent statically by typing the following command

```
java -javaagent:target/agent.jar -jar example-app.jar
```

I get the following output:

```
Running premain
Before ClassPool Instantiation
Before ClassPool Instantiation
Before ClassPool Instantiation
Hello World!
Before ClassPool Instantiation
Before ClassPool Instantiation
Before ClassPool Instantiation
Before ClassPool Instantiation
```

It seems the print statement after the ClassPool object is instantiatet is not executed.
** Example class is just printing "Hello World" onto the console

I have tried other examples provided in the internet, with the same result. Wrapping it into try/catch block doesn't throw an error either.

Comment: Please add a `try {} catch {}` block around it and log/print it. Instrumentation is known to discard anything that is thrown.

Comment: `new ClassPool()` causes the loading of the `ClassPool` class which will then be passed to your class file transformer. Since your class file transformer depends on the class unconditionally, there is no other way for the JVM than to ignore your transformer to fix the problem. The first thing your transformer should do, is to inspect the `className` argument, to check whether the class is one you’re interested in (which should exclude the classes your transformer depends on) and return `null` otherwise.